# Compile .sh for Unix & Mac with nessesary files

Tags: compilation, sh

Is there a way to make it so I can compile a .sh for Unix & Mac so :

1. The code is obfuscated
2. I can put the necessary files for it to work inside the actual compiled product

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You might have more luck on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

I would never recommend obfuscating code.
But if you must.

https://github.com/Aralhach/bashobfus/tree/master

This program:

```
Flatten indentation
Remove full-line comments (except the initial hashbang (#!)) and blank lines
Renames all lowercase variables in basic declarations (to avoid renaming variables like PATH), for     
loops, array access, and 'read' statements.
```

Comment: how do i add in the necessary files in the executable, i just want that to be hidden

Comment: ? What do you mean by that? Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: I have file.jar which I have certain arguments inside the .sh to load up the .jar correctly. I want the .jar to be sort of embedded inside the executable

Comment: i would need to look at both codes to tell you how to go about this.

Comment: "set +v
java -Xincgc -Xmx800m -jar minecraft.jar
sleep" is the .sh & minecraft .jar is simply a customised minecraft launcher